# Error on executing sess.run() ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, numpy-ndarray

This error is generated when I try to run the training step. The dataset is MNIST dataset from Kaggle. I'm using a neural network to predict the handwritten digits:

Input Data : `[33600, 784]` reshaped into `[784, 33600]`

Neural network architecture:

Layer 1 has W1  1000 by 784  relu
  Layer 2 has W2  1000 by 1000  relu
  Layer 3 has W3  500 by 1000  relu
  Layer 4 has W4  200 by 500  relu
  Layer 5 has W5  10 by 200 with  softmax
  No biases used

Code:

```py
print(X_train[:, 0].reshape(-1, 1).shape,"   ",y_train[:,0].reshape(-1,1).shape)`
```

Output: `(784, 1)`     `(10, 1)`

Code:

```py
X, Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[784, None]), tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[10, None])

logits = forward_propagation(X, parameters)

cost = compute_cost(logits, Y)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-3).minimize(cost)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    _,c = sess.run([optimizer,cost], feed_dict= {X:X_train[:,0].reshape(-1,1),
                                                 Y:y_train[:, 0].reshape(-1,1)})
print(c)
```

Output:

```
ValueError         Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-41-f78f499b0606> in <module>()
8 with tf.Session() as sess:
9     sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
---> 10     _,c = sess.run([optimizer,cost], feed_dict= 
{X:np.asarray(X_train), Y:np.asarray(y_train)})
11 print(c)

.......
.......

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Please correct the code if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. As mentioned in the answers of many other similar questions, the problem is generally with the shape & type of arrays provided to the feed_dict.
My main focus was only on X:X_train[:,0].reshape(-1,1) but it was correct shape and type. The error was in Y:y_train[:, 0].reshape(-1,1). I could not detect this error because I applied one_hot_encoding on y_train but forgot to use the .toarray() method after tranforming. So the shape of y_train appeared to be correct but actually it was wrong.

As a general suggestion after going through many similar questions, I would say to thoroughly check shapes, types and content of the arrays being fed to the feed_dict.